# Why programmable interval timer cannot work while other device work?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, interrupt

My OS can properly handle keyboard and mouse interrupt, but PIT cannot work at all.

```c
void int_handler_32() {
    PIC_send_EOI(0);
    term_printf("-");
    kPrintf("!");
}

void timer_init() {
    kPrintf("!");
    cli();
    uint16_t hz = TIMER_IN_HZ / TIMER_TARGET_HZ;
    outb(0x43, 0x34);
    outb(0x40, hz & 0xFF);
    outb(0x40, hz >> 8);
    // sti();
}

/**************************/

void idt_init() {
    pic_init();
    // PIC_remap(0x20, 0x28);

    idtr.base = (uint32_t)idt;
    idtr.limit = sizeof(idt_entry_t) * 256 - 1;

    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        idt_set_descriptor(i, 0, 0, 0);
    }

#define ADD_INT(n) \
    void isr_wrapper_##n(); \
    idt_set_descriptor(n, 0x08, isr_wrapper_##n, 0x8E)

    ADD_INT(32); // timer
    ADD_INT(33); // keyboard
    ADD_INT(44); // mouse
    ADD_INT(128);// custom

    asm volatile ("lidt %0":: "m" (idtr));

    asm volatile ("sti");
    IRQ_set_mask(0x20);
    IRQ_set_mask(0x21);
    IRQ_set_mask(0x2C);
}

/**************************/

static Queue qKeyboard;
static Queue qMouse;

void int_handler_33() {
    PIC_send_EOI(1);
    uint8_t ch = inb(0x60);
    queue_push(&qKeyboard, &ch);
    // kPrintf("+K %d\n", ch);
}

void int_handler_44() {
    PIC_send_EOI(12);
    uint8_t ch = inb(0x60);
    queue_push(&qMouse, &ch);
    // kPrintf("+M %xb\n", ch);
}
```

```sh
# codes generate a .s file
for i in 32 33 44 128; do
    cat << EOF
.global isr_wrapper_$i
.type isr_wrapper_$i, @function
isr_wrapper_$i:
    pusha
    cld
    call int_handler_$i
    popa
    iret
EOF
done
```

I've just have no idea now. By outputting to qemu's port 0x3F8, I've confirmed that isr_wrapper 33, 44 are called but 32 aren't.

Can anyone gives some suggestions? I've read the `I Can't Get Interrupts Working` article on osdev, but cannot find any clue.

---

After debugging with bochs, the logs shows that IRQ0 is changed but it doesn't signal me.

```
01399359954d[PIC   ] IRQ line 0 now high
01399399946d[PIC   ] IRQ line 0 now low
01399399950d[PIC   ] IRQ line 0 now high
01399421000d[PIC   ] IRQ line 1 now high
01399421000d[PIC   ] signalling IRQ #1
01399421032d[PIC   ] IO write to 0x0020 = 0x20
01399421051d[PIC   ] IRQ line 1 now low
01399439946d[PIC   ] IRQ line 0 now low
01399439950d[PIC   ] IRQ line 0 now high
01399479942d[PIC   ] IRQ line 0 now low
01399479946d[PIC   ] IRQ line 0 now high
```

Comparing to line 1(keyboard), it should signal IRQ #0 but it doesn't.
I've searched [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244011/why-isnt-my-isr-for-irq0-8253-timer-interrupt-from-the-8259-executed) which is quite similar to my problem. His problem is that he doesn't set IF bit with sti, but in my case this couldn't happen as keyboard works.

Comment: Looks like you're initializing 0x40 twice.  Maybe one of those should be 0x41.

Comment: @ErikEidt Depending on the value you write to port 0x41, you have to write two bytes (Low and high byte of a 16-bit word) to port 0x40. Value 0x34 is one of the values expecting two bytes at port 0x40.

Comment: Have you tried to send 0x30 (Send EOI for IRQ 0) to port 0x20 after `idt_init()`? Maybe the PIC is has sent an interrupt request to the CPU but the CPU was not ready, yet, and now it is waiting for an acknowledgement...

Comment: @MartinRosenau Thanks for your advice. I've tried manually sending EOI after timer and idt init, but it seems not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After carefully checking my code, I've find the reason!

I used to set IMR before the main loop like below (for keyboard and mouse message handling) and have forgotten that (I think I set this mask right after `idt_init`).

```c
void input_start() {
    outb(0x21, 0xF9);
    outb(0xA1, 0xEF);
}
```

I hard-coded the mask which set the bit zero which make PIC ignore the timer. After remove this function, timer works.